# Расположение кнопок поверх канваса

Tags: java, android, android-button, android-canvas

Пишу игру под android. Нужно расположить кнопку **make a move** в правом нижнем углу, а все остальное заполнить канвасом. Пока я клею канвас следующим образом:

Есть соответствующий класс MyCanvas

```
public class MyCanvas extends View {
public MyCanvas(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```

И активность **GameActivity** (на которую клеем канвас), в которой прописано:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new MyCanvas(this));
....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот отличное описание, как это сделать - [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11859081/how-can-i-create-a-button-on-canvas-in-android-and-link-that-button-to-an-image).

Если коротко, то рисуете вашу кнопку на `Canvas`, после чего проверяете по координатам куда нажал пользователь.

Comment: Спасибо, но лучше воспользуюсь вторым вариантом, описанном по ссылке (где канвас помещается внутрь RelativeLayout).

Comment: Дело в том, что все скорее зависит от задачи, поэтому если для вас это решение более подходит - то я рад.